# Obtaining a token using IHttpclientFactory

Tags: c#, ihttpclientfactory

I've written the code below in IhttpclientFactory. For some reasons, the code is not returning a token. oauth is returning null.
I will appreciate it if someone would kindly have a look and tell me where I've gone wrong. thank you

```
    private async Task<OAuth>Authenticate()
    {
        //build request
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/oauth/token");

        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new OAuth() {grant_type="client_credentials",client_id="",client_secret=""}));

        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-urlencoded");
                  
        //build client
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/+json"));

        // send the request
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        OAuth oauth = null;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //deserialise

            var oAuth = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuth>(responseStream);
        }
        return oauth;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the value of `response.IsSuccessStatusCode`?

Comment: Is client_secret really empty or is that just an edit to keep it secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different OAuth variables 'oauth' and 'oAuth'.  C# identifiers are case-sensitive.

Should be something like

```
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       throw new InvalidOperationExeption($"OAuth Request Failed With Status code {response.StatusCode}");
    }
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var oAuth = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuth>(responseString);
    return oAuth;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But changing it to David's suggestion does not solve the problem. it still returns null value for OAuth

Comment: So, what does `responseString` look like?  Is it a JSON representation of an `OAuth` object?

Comment: Thanks David, your suggestion actually works